# How to specify Primary Key when using vba to create tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, recordset

I've updated the code with the suggestion given below, which I've tested and works great, for quick reference for future users.

---

I'm using the below code to create linked tables without having to set up a DSN for each user, how can I specify a primary key as you would be asked if connecting manually:

```
Dim sConnect    As String
Dim db          As DAO.Database
Dim tdf         As DAO.TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb

Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef
tdf.Name = "dbo_vwFeedback" ' - -- --- This is the Label that you see in Access...
tdf.Connect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=server01\serverinstance;DATABASE=db_name;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
tdf.SourceTableName = "vwFeedback" ' - -- --- This is the actual name in SQL Server, minus the owner.
db.TableDefs.Append tdf
CurrentDb.Execute "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK_dbo_vwFeedback_PrimaryKey ON dbo_vwFeedback (DataSetID, FeedbackRef) WITH PRIMARY"
```

NOTE: The above is for a SQL Server VIEW, it is identical for a SQL Server TABLE, but you do not need the `CurrentDB.Execute` line (if your primary key is correctly set up on the Server).

The code is in the place of linking a table and specifying a primary key manually.

If you do not specifying the creation of an index for SQL Server VIEWs manually or with the above method, you will only get a READ ONLY view and you may experience erroneous data returned, see comments below for examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After linking the table with the code from your question, you need to do this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SomeIndex ON SomeTable (PrimaryKeyColumn) WITH PRIMARY"
```

See [VBA Code to Add Linked Table with Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602687) for a complete example.

Note that you do **not** need to do this if you link a **table** - Access will detect the primary key automatically (as Remou made clear in his comment below).

But when you link a SQL Server **view** in Access, it is **very important** to specify a proper primary key for the view in Access.
If you specify the wrong key (= you select columns that don't identify a unique record) or no key at all, Access will link the view as read-only table (as you already noticed).

Plus, it will screw up the displayed rows - see [Why does linked view give different results from MS Access vs SQL Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350928) for more explanation.
*(read my answer, **and** my comments under the other answer)*

Comment: It might be an idea to check that an index has not already been assigned (`tdf.Indexes.Count`) and whether or not it is primary (`tdf.Indexes(0).Primary`). If you link a table with a suitable index, it will be used.

Comment: It depends. I'm using a local table which contains a list of server tables/views to link, and I have a function that loops through that list, and deletes and re-links each table. So I *know* that the table doesn't already have an index at that moment.

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that an SQL Server table that has a primary key set on SQL server and is linked through a TableDef, as in the OP, will have a primary key set automatically, without any further intervention the name will be the same as the SQL Server name.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I should have mentioned this in my answer. But the OP is linking a **view**, not a table. And when you link a view, you **have** to explicitly specify the key if you don't want to run into the problems described in my answer.