# Access Query based on ComboBox returning more values than selected in combo box

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

The following SQL is a simple query but I can't figure out why it is returning more results than it should.  The combobox 5 on Form1 has a drop down selection of 1,2,3,4, or 5.  If I leave this blank, it will return the entire data set, how if I select 2 as an example, the data set returns data where Field1 is 2 as well as others such as 1,3,4, or 5.

Any thoughts? I am connected to Table1 through an ODBC connection

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.Field1)=Forms!Form1!CMB5 Or IsNull(Forms!Form1!CMB5)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently details are important(jk they always are).  when creating an ODBC connection, it asks a very important question which is to select a unique identifier.  I did not select a unique identifier which was causing the errors with my views.  I found the answer here "[Why does linked view give different results from MS Access vs SQL Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350928/why-does-linked-view-give-different-results-from-ms-access-vs-sql-manager)".